# Open multiple URLs in second browser instance?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have two browser windows side by side.

I want to drag&drop an element (with defined URLs) from the left window to the tabs area on the right window and it should open multiple URLs.

Is that even possible?

I found scripts that open multiple URLs as new tabs, but not in an desired browser window.

Qould be fine if it works at least in Chrome.

Comment: You may be able to build something using a packaged Chrome App, but generally, browser tabs are sandboxed - they don't know anything about other tabs running, and certainly nothing about other window instances of Chrome!

Comment: The tabs don't need to know of each other. I just want to drop an element over the second browser and it should open defined URLs as new tabs. No hacking. Just like marking multiple favorites in the fav manager and dragging them to the tab area.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what I am saying is that DOM elements do not (generally) have access to the tab system in a browser, let alone other windows. You cannot drag an element outside of its containing Document Object Model.

Comment: I can drag one link, just not multiple (gets treated as text), so there is access.

Comment: Only for anchor elements, and that has less to do with moving DOM elements, but rather Chrome acting on the http protocol.